# animate() only runs once

Tags: jquery, html

I have a block of code that collapses one div and widens another on the click of a button. The widening div portion only iterates once and then does no more, while the collapsible div continues to do it's thing.

In the code I declare a variable named `divSize` to get the size of the `.widenDiv`, my reasoning is because there will be differing screen sizes that will not have the same pixel width, so I want to keep the UI as standard as possible.

When I click the collapse button a second time, the div will shrink back to its original size. The animation works as expected, however it only works once.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var divSize = $('.widenDiv').width();
  $('.widenDiv').width() == divSize;

  $('#divAnimateBtn').click(function() {
    $('#collapseDiv').slideToggle("normal");

    if ($('.widenDiv').width() == divSize) {
      $('.widenDiv').animate({
        width: "90%"
      });
    } else {
      $('.widenDiv').animate({
        width: divSize
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="body-content col-sm-12 col-lg-12" style=" margin-top: -10px; height: 100%; background-color: white;">
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 clearfix left-column-container" style="background-color: white; float: left; max-height: 100vh; ">
    <div class="left-column" id="Test" style="background-color: white;">
      <button id="divAnimateBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-info"></button>
      <div class="collapse in" id="collapseDiv">
        <p>filler</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9 widenDiv" style="background-color: white; text-align: center;">
    <div class="right-column-bottom col-lg-12" style="border: 1px solid black; padding-top: 5px; margin-top: 5px;">
      <p>filler</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Updated code that fixed my issue:

I added an onClick() function to the button.

```
 <button id="divAnimateBtn" type ="button" class="btn btn-info" onclick="extendDiv()" style="float: left;"><<</button>
```

using vanilla js with a few jQuery lines of code I implemented the intended UI animation.

```
var exBtn = document.createElement("BUTTON"); //button is declared so I can slide out again.
var colBtn = document.getElementById("divAnimateBtn");
function extendDiv() {
            document.getElementById("widenDiv").style.width = "96%";
            $('#collapseDiv').slideToggle("slow");
            colBtn.style.display= "none";
            exBtn.innerHTML = ">>";
            document.getElementById("right-column-container").prepend(exBtn);
            exBtn.style = "border: 2px solid #0066CC; float: left; background-color: #fff; border-radius: 5px; color: #0066CC; font-size: 14px;";
            exBtn.onclick = shrinkDiv; //new function for the replacement button


        }

        function shrinkDiv() {
            exBtn.remove();
            colBtn.style.display = "inline";
             $('#collapseDiv').slideToggle("slow");
            document.getElementById("widenDiv").style.width = "" //<- sets CSS back to initial value;      
        }
```

set the animation speed for the widening div in CSS

```
#widenDiv{
    transition: 1s;
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's because `$('.widenDiv').width()` returns number without units? Try adding `width: divSize + 'px'` to your animation. Also try to create SO Snippet with sample HTML and JS code

Comment: `width()` may not get the correct width - it may be `outerWidth()` you need if you animate `width`.  One way to make sure it is the same is to use `.width(divSize)` and move your animation to a css transition (or just add and remove a class that does the animation)

Comment: `$('.widenDiv').width() == divSize;` is not the valid form to set this http://api.jquery.com/width/  It would help if you create a working example with the HTML in a snippet

Comment: It could be the container width , try to get the window width

Comment: Based upon the markup, this may have bootstrap?

Comment: NOTE: Nothing with this class is in the HTML there; `$('.widenDiv')` so at this juncture I have to vote to close here.

Comment: apologies, it's the class right-column-container, i just changed the reference in jQuery so that people would know what my intentions were with that particular div

Comment: I solved my own problem. I switched to using Vanilla JavaScript instead of just jQuery. updated code in main question.